# How is it possible for OS processes to manage User processes while they themselves are processes?

Tags: operating-system, cpu-architecture

Recently, I have been reading about Operating Systems, and this bugs me a lot.
How is it really possible for one process to manage other process.

Basically a CPU simply executes instructions, after executing one instruction, then it executes the instruction at address pointed by IP and increments the IP.

Let me elaborate my doubt with an example. Lets say I have an User process (or simply a process) which is being executed by CPU. Lets say, it has 'n' instruction and currently executing 'i'th instruction. IP points to (i+1)th instruction.
So, at this point how can all other OS processes like Scheduler, dispatcher etc... comes into play, Since CPU is already executing another process.

One solution (Just a guess), I could think of is , the use of Interrupts and Interrupt Service Routines.

But its only a guess.

PS: I searched and couldn't find any satisfying answer.

Comment: OS is a system, not a process. It is an "operating" system that manages how the hardware would be used. To run a process in OS, there are numerous other helper programs (which may or may not be native to the OS) are available.

Comment: According to my understanding, An Operating System conducts its management activities with help of OS processes right ? I think you are not really getting my point. Please read my question once again.

Comment: Yes that is correct, though a language lawyer could question the wording.

Comment: The OS kernel is a state-machine of code and data.  It has no thread of execution within itself, it needs no stack, (though changing to kernel stacks are often used as an implementation/optimization).  It is not a classical process - it is code that is entered from process threads upon hardware interrupts and syscalls.  If there are no hardware interrupts, and no system calls, the kernel code is not entered or executed.  'the use of Interrupts' - yes, essential.  'I searched and couldn't find any satisfying answer' - really?  What search string/s did you try?

Comment: @MartinJames Thanks, Your answer helped me to understand the concept clearly. Its the distinction between an OS kernel and other OS processes which are similar to user processes that was bugging me. Also, If I was able to find a satisfying answer, why would I ask here ?

Comment: @MathewsGeorge top of the 'Related' list opposite is a similar Q&A...

Comment: Oops. That really didn't caught my eye.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the help of the hardware, ticks causes the CPU to execute operating system code. This code checks the system state and the time that has elapsed since the beginning of this process execution. At this point, the operating system can decide to schedule a different process. All it has to do is save the current state of the running process with the process that is about to start running. (basically changing the content of the registers and saving the registers state before changing to the new process).

Eventually, the CPU is taken away even if the process doesn't want to yield it.

To address your concern, there are no operating system processes in the way you think... it isn't like there are OS processes in the queue waiting among other processes....

Comment: 'ticks causes the CPU to execute operating system code' - while not untrue in general, it is highly misleading.  There are many interrupts that can cause a scheduling run.